# Fixed position not working for header

Tags: html, css, header, position, fixed

I am trying to make my header fixed so that it will scroll along with the page for both mobile and desktop. The thing is that it was working earlier but as I kept coding, it stopped working. I have tried getting rid of codes to see if any of them was effecting it but that wasn't the case.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='title'>
    </div>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
      <li><a href="conferences.html">Conferences</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

<div class='content isOpen'>
<header>
    <div class="mobile grid">
    <div class="unit unit-s-2-3 unit-m-1-3 unit-l-1-3">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" class="flex-logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="unit unit-s-1-3 unit-m-2-3 unit-m-2-3-1 unit-l-2-3">
        <a class='button'></a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid desktop">
        <div class="unit unit-s-1 unit-m-1-3 unit-l-1-3">
            <div class="unit unit-s-1 unit-m-1-3 unit-l-1-3 left">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-square.svg" class="flex-logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="unit unit-s-1 unit-m-2-3 unit-l-2-3 desktop">
                <h1>International Academy of Science, Engineering, and Techonology</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="unit unit-s-1 unit-m-2-3 unit-l-2-3 desktop-nav">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="conferences.html">Conferences</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header> <!-- END HEADER -->
</div></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 999;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #AB1917;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 135px;
  background-color: #AB1917;
height: 100%;
right: 0;
}

.content {
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transform: translate3d(-135px,0,0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.content.isOpen {
  transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
}
```

And here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').toggleClass('isOpen');
  });
});
</script>
```

I have tried specifying a height for the header and even using a sticky nav plugin to make it fixed; however none of those has worked. And I am not sure what to do anymore.

If you want to view the issue on the website, you can see it here: [www.international-aset.com/intaset](http://international-aset.com/intaset)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it depending on browser? In Safari the header is fixed.

Comment: It doesn't work on chrome and firefox but the code isn't specific for any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have a transform on your content element.

This is because the transform creates a new local coordinate system, this means that fixed positioning becomes fixed to the transformed element, rather than the viewport.

I can see you are using transform for you mobile nav, a few solutions would be

- Use a negative margin instead of transform
- Absoultely position your parent element and use left -180px etc
- Move your nav outside of the container, fix its position then add padding at the top of your page.

Hope one of those work for you

Comment: I am using the transform on my content for my mobile navigation (it is an off canvas navigation). I have tried specifying "transfrom: translate3d(0,0,0)" on my header to see if that would fix the issue. Unfortunately, it didn't. So I got rid of the transform element on my content for the desktop and it works!!!!

Problem is that I need the transform for my mobile to make the mobile navigation work. Is there any way to get around that to make my header fixed?

Comment: Perhaps I am doing this wrong ... I tried the negative margin, it isn't working nor does absolute position. My navigation is already outside of the content container (class of the container is .content) and it has an absolute position on it. I tried changing the position for that to see if it will change anything but nope.

I think the negative margin is my solution since the translate element is what preventing my header. Would it be possible for you to provide me an example code that I could use to better understand it?

Thank you!